# Wifi no longer available in Hera OS 5.1.7

Tags: release-hera, wifi

I'm running Hera 5.1.7 on a Lenovo Thinkpad. This morning when I turned on my computer the Wifi Settings were gone completely. I've tried restarting the computer and the wifi settings are still missing.

When I run `sudo lshw -C network`, the output is

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
  description: Network controller
  product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  version: 78
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:ee2200000-ee201fff
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 1f.6
  bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
  logical name: enp0s31f6
  version: 21
  serial: 98:fa:9b:33:22:e8
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
  resources: irq:146 memory:ee300000-ee31ffff
```

Comment: try this: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1603#issue-965454894

Comment: I ran this and received the following message,

`linux-headers-4.15.0-156-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-156.163).`

The wireless settings are still unavailable.

Comment: First remove `bcmwl-kernel-source` if you have already installed.  Then run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. After this install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` again

Comment: Thanks for the help @shrestha_aj 

I followed those steps and after trying to install `bcmwl-kernel-source` I got the following error - 

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available`

Answer (score 0):

Connect a lan cable and install your wifi drivers:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 firmware-b43-installer
```

By the way, you can update to [elementary 6](https://elementary.io/) if you want. The solution for elementary 6 is:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Thanks @maccer, do you know why/how the wifi drivers were dropped? I've been running Hera without issues for years now.

Comment: After running `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 firmware-b43-installer` and rebooting my system, the wireless settings are still not visible.

Here is the output from `sudo lshw -C network` is the same as before.